# PSTools not working in SSH

Tags: ssh, cygwin

When using PSTools (sysinternals) via SSH, you may notice that it stalls when you try the command. If it does this, you probably have not agreed to the license terms for each pstools command.

Solution: Log directly into the Windows computer via Console or RDP as the user you wish to SSH in as and execute each command in pstools that you need to use. You will get the license confirmation and hit accept. Once this is done, you will now be able to use the commands via SSH :)

Note: pslist is a great alternative to TOP. I have open issues with TOP command in cygwin where it only lists current user (not very useful). pslist does not have this issue.

Cheers,

-JsD

Answer (score 3):

Or use the `-accepteula` switch that is [supported by all PSTools](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sysinternals/archive/2006/12/05/updates-pstools-and-sysinternalssuite.aspx).

Comment: This answer is better than the solution provided by the OP, as it works even when the utility is run via a service. We had this situation today where a job was being run by a job scheduler, under an account that noone is ever allowed to use directly.  This was the ideal solution in this case.